# declare 'this' value for helper function

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.0, tsc

I have a class:

```
const helper = function(val){
   console.log(this.a);
   console.log(this.b);
   this.bar();
};

export class Foo {

 public b = '45'
 private a = 15;

 bar(){

 }

 myMethod(){
    return helper.apply(this,arguments);
 }

}
```

the problem is, in the helper function, it doesn't know what the context is (what the value of 'this' is).

Is there a way for me to tell typescript that the value for this in the helper function is an instance of `Foo`?

(the reason I use the helper function is to create true private methods).

Comment: Here's a StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dzmfb1 (this is an Angular one but I'm just using main.ts as a typescript file here). Check the browser console, it seems to behave like you want it to.

Comment: that's working at runtime (naturally) ... but at compile time, TS doesn't know what `this` is (it cannot know because it's dynamic, unless you tell TS that it's always one kind of type)

Comment: What about `let self: Foo = this as Foo;` and then use `self`? Could also replace `this` with `(this as Foo)` everytime you use it.

Comment: that might work idk, if you think it works, add an answer I will upvote

Comment: Just did. Not 100% sure this is what you meant but this should let your compiler/IDE know you're working with a `Foo` instance.

Comment: Why not `const helper = function(t: Foo, val){
    console.log(t.a);
}`? It would be statically typed.

Comment: @zerkms I tried that actually and it said private methods/members of `t` could not be accessed by `t` even though it was declared as `Foo`, lame!

Comment: Oh right. So you want a private method that is not available from the JS runtime, I see.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this on top of your helper function:

```
let self: Foo = this as Foo;
// use self instead of this below
```

Alternatively, you could replace all instances of `this` in it with `(this as Foo)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the type of `this` for any `function` by adding an extra parameter named `this`. The `this` parameter will not be emitted to Javascript, it will be just for the benefit of the compiler to be able to type check your code:

```
const helper = function(this: Foo, val: number){
    console.log(this.a); /// error a is private
    console.log(this.b);
    this.bar();
 };
```

This will not however break encapsulation, you will still not be able to access private properties from outside the class, so unless you create the function inside the class it will still give an error as above. For functions defined inside the class it will not give errors:

```
export class Foo {

    public b = '45'
    private a = 15;
    bar() { }
    createHelper() {
        return function (this: Foo, val: number) {
            console.log(this.a);
            console.log(this.b);
            this.bar();
        };
    }

    myMethod() {
        return this.createHelper().apply(this, arguments);
    }

}
```

Comment: @AlexanderMills I don't post untested code, it compiles ;)